# Interior Dash Lights & AC Control Lights Are Out

Tags: ford, fuse, explorer, lights, fuse-panel

2 days ago when I would crank up my 1996 Explorer and cut the lights on my dash lights and AC lights would flicker then come on, well this morning when I cut on my vehicle the lights did not come on, no flicker, just nothing!  Now when I say lights, I mean the light that illuminates the speedometer and gas gauge, and the lights that illuminate the AC Controls.  The "warning" lights as I will call them still come on, such as gas light, air bag light etc when the car is cranked.

What do I need to to do to get those lights to come on, so I can see how fast I am driving while dark out ?

Comment: Most dash lights have a dimmer control, maybe it got set to off, that or the fuse is blown.

Comment: @Moab - not the dimmer switch.  I can flip the switch all the way up and it turns on the interior dome lights etc.  Do you know which fuse controls these elements?

Comment: I use a test light to find bad fuses in the interior fuse panel. Sorry I don't have an image of the fuse box or a fuse number.

Comment: Using google i think it is fuse 15, should be a 7.5 amp.

Comment: Dimmer switch has 2 functions, the dimmer part can be bad and still turn on the dome light.

Comment: So Bob, what fixed it?

Comment: @Moab - thankfully it was just the fuse.  Replacing it got it going again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 possible causes I can think of.

1. Dimmer switch had been turned all the way down or the dimmer part of the switch is bad. You can still turn on the dome light even when the dimmer part is inoperative.
2. Fuse for instrument Cluster is bad, I think it is Fuse #15 (7.5amp) on that model. Interior fuse panel.